# Using percentage to size a grid item within the grid containing block

Tags: css, css-grid, percentage

I have a little confusion about the percentage with grid.

I know that when a container a has a specific width in pixel for example, then any child with the value of 100% of the width that child will take same width of the parent.

However, when the parent with **display grid**, and specific width in pixel for example. besides, **grid areas**. As the exmaple below. Then each child take a specific area of the grid.

My qusetion is, when a child is given the width of **100%**, will that width be **100%** of the parent width or **100%** of the grid area that was given to the child?

```
    main {
        max-width: 1200px;
        min-width: 750px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: minmax(6%, 8%) minmax(300px, 1fr) minmax(400px, 2fr);
       
        grid-template-areas:
            "sec_nav main_head main_head"
            "sec_nav welcome welcome"
            "sec_nav main_content main_content"
            "sec_nav main_content main_content"
            "sec_nav note .";
    }

 main .main-header {
      grid-area: main_head;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item-sizing)

> A grid item is sized within the containing block **defined by its grid area**.

So the containing block is defined by the grid area and the not the parent element and the containing block is the one used as reference for width percentage calculation

> `<percentage>`
>
> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated **box's containing block**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-width-property)</sup>